# Thinking of storing serialized java objects into cassandra as JSON. What is the catch?

Tags: java, json, cassandra

I am using Cassandra 1.2.2. I am finding it so easy to use Jackson to map my objects to and fro json and java for storing in database. I am actually tempted to do this to all of my data. My question is, Is this a good idea? What are the disadvantages of doing this to my application. My first guess is probably more processing overheads but is the juice worth the squeeze? and are there any other disadvantages that i need to know about?

Comment: I was wondering, could you clarify (or be more explicit) what you mean by the following sentence: " I am finding it so easy to use Jackson to map my objects to and fro json and java for storing in database". Are you saying that you are using "Jackson" to map objects to JSON strings and parse them back to objects?

Comment: @CharlieParker yes, that's precisely what I mean, is there a problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One disadvantage is that to modify the data you have to read in the original, deserialize, make your change, serialize and write out the whole object. In Cassandra, writes are much more efficient than reads so it is beneficial to avoid reads before writes if possible.

The alternative is to use separate columns for each field in your JSON.  You can use composite columns for multi-dimensional data.

So if you had the data:

```
{
  name: "fred"
  address: "some town"
  age: 42
}
```

and you wanted to change the address, if you had these as separate Cassandra columns you'd just insert a column called address. If you had the JSON serialized you'd have to do much more work. This doesn't apply if your data is write-once.

Even if your data is write-once, if you just wanted to read one field from the data you can just read that column if stored separately rather than reading the whole thing and deserializing. This only applies if you want to read parts of your data.

In conclusion, there could be significant performance advantages to using separate columns if you have to update your data or if you only want to read parts at once.

Comment: Thank you so much man you are always so thorough in your answers and explanations. I think I'm doing away with JSON completely from data that may need updating. As a result this will lead to many rows each for every object as opposed to many columns in a row each column representing the Jasonified object. which one is better performancewise for cassandra alone, 1 million rows each with 10 columns or 100 rows each with 100K columns?

Comment: It depends on your read pattern. The rows are stored essentially randomly on disk so reading from lots of rows at the same time will be slow. But if rows get too big then you lose your scalability since whole rows are stored on a single node (plus replicas).